# symfony 3 - url image from database

Tags: php, database, image, symfony

I wanted to display the url of an image from bdd in my file twig I receive an error of the image like the:
[image: bdd]

this is my bdd : 
[image: bdd]

and my view from twig :

```
{% extends '@App/layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %} Illustration {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
    <h2> {{ imageFormation.image.nom }}</h2>
    <hr>
    <img src=" {{ imageFormation.image.url |raw }} "/><br><br>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Can you help me solve my problem please?
 i dont know why i cant get the real image.

edit :

```
/**
     * @Route("/formation/{formation}" , name="image")
     * @param $image
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function imageFormationAction($formation){


        $doctrine = $this->container->get('doctrine');
        $em = $doctrine->getManager();

        $imageRepository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Formation');

        $imageFormation = $imageRepository->findOneByid($formation);

        return $this->render('@App/formation/formationImage.html.twig', array(
            'imageFormation' => $imageFormation
        ));
    }
```

[image: bdd]

[image: bdd]

Comment: Why would you need absolute paths for your images? The job can be easily done using relative paths. Just put the images inside the `web/directory1` and then use `<img src="{{ asset('directory1/' ~ imageFormation.image.url }}">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image url must be relative to web directory, like this `fichier\Mention.jpg`, not the image's path in your file system `C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\MonProjetCv\web\fichier\Mention.jpg`.

Save a relative path to your image file in the database (url equal `fichier\Mention.jpg`), and use `asset` function in your twig file:

```
{% extends '@App/layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %} Illustration {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
    <h2> {{ imageFormation.image.nom }}</h2>
    <hr>
    <img src=" {{ asset(imageFormation.image.url); }} "/><br><br>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: ohhhh thank you very much now its good. i was know its was a problem with the url but i was not try your method. "path" is not good for this function, "asset" is good and now i have what i wanted :). thank you very much

Comment: I mistakenly wrote `path` instead of `asset`. `asset` is what you want, `path` used to refer to route. I will correct the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this way?

```
<img src='{{ asset("IMAGE_DIRECTORY_PATH/"~ image.url)}}' />
```

Comment: i did that : <img src='{{ asset("C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\MonProjetCv\web\img"~ imageFormation.image.url)}}' />      and its still the same thing

Comment: Please try: <img src='{{ asset("Symfony/MonProjetCv/web/img"~ imageFormation.image.url)}}' />

Comment: i tried it but its style same, i dont know if the problem from ma database. i need the image from database cause i need to do a loop from an URL of a page. i will edit my question to see what i need